# CYGWIN, GDAL: batch processing not working; gdalwarp on Cygwin error: "too many points"

Tags: cygwin, gis, gdal

I'm attempting to mass convert the Sinusoidal projections of hundreds of MODIS single-band files to WGS84 in a single directory (which were extracted from HDF-EOS format using gdal_translate) using GDAL in Cygwin.

When I execute the **gdalwarp** command on a single file, it executes the command successfully and the result is my desired output:

```
$ gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=sinu +R=6371007.181 +nadgrids=@null +wktext" -t_srs EPSG:4326 testfile.tif testfile_proj_1.tif
Processing testfile.tif [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. -1) for imag
e testfile.tif.
...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

However, when I try to process the aforementioned hundreds of files using a for loop...:

```
$ for f in *.tif; do
> gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=sinu +R=6371007.181 +nadgrids=@null +wktext" -t_srs EPSG:4326 "$f" "${f%.*}.tif"
```

..., it returns errors:

```
ERROR 1: Too many points (529 out of 529) failed to transform, unable to compute
 output bounds.
Warning 1: Unable to compute source region for output window 0,0,2400,2400, skip
ping.
```

I am baffled as to why the command will work on a single file, but won't in a mass conversion.

How do I get this to work? Are there any alternatives to GDAL that I can use to mass reproject TIFFs if this is a wall I hit?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: may be it is a single file (or few ones) that have problems ? Or you have problems on all the files ?

Comment: The singular file I executed the command on was part of the package, but the command line returns these errors only when I'm attempting the command on the entirety of the package.

Comment: the `for` cycle (that misses a  `done`)  is applying the same command to every single file (o so it seems). So I assume that some files fail but most pass. Have you tried to identify the failing ones ?

Comment: None of the files pass - they return this error individually when using batch processing. When I execute the command on single files, it accomplishes the task successfully.

Comment: can we find some files anywhere ?